# Solving quadratic inequality to get the final answer

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Okay, so I'm self studying my A level mathematics and I don't have a tutor to ask from so I hope someone can help me here.

My question is:

> Q: The equation of curve is $y=\dfrac{12}x$ and the of a line $L$ is
>    $2 x + y= k$ where $k$ is a constant. Find the set of values of $k$ for which $L$ does not intersect the curve.

So here's my answer:

Ans:

•Solving simultaneously,

$$\frac{12}x = kx - 2x^2$$

$$2x^2 - kx + 12 = 0$$

•Since $L$ doesn't intersect there are no real roots, therefore the discriminant is

$$b^2 - 4ac < 0$$

•substituting values

$$(-k)^2 - 4(2)(12) < 0$$

$$k^2 - 96 < 0$$

$$(k - \sqrt{96})(k + \sqrt{96}) < 0$$

Now I don't know how to get the answer. I know to draw a graph, but for $x$ values, I don't understand how to use it for $k$ or neither do I know any other method.

(Can you keep the explanation simple in A level boundaries?)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Your working so far is fine. Now you have
$$(k+\sqrt{96})(k-\sqrt{96})<0$$
To satisfy the inequality, either of the factors must be negative and the other positive. The range that satisfies that is $$-\sqrt{96}<k<\sqrt{96}$$

---

You can actually just treat $k$ as if it is an $x$. It's just a dummy variable. Don't be too concerned about the 'appearance'.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @MushrafAltaf No worry! I just finished A Level a few months ago too :)